# multiplying transposed matrix with jblas

Tags: matrix-multiplication

I'm implementing backpropagation and gradient descent with Jblas.

Layer 1 is a vector A: DoubleMatrix(M, 1)

Layer 2 is a vector B: DoubleMatrix(N, 1)

Between them are weights W: DoubleMatrix(M, N)

During the forward pass, I'm multiplying B = W \times A

```
W.mmulti(A, B)
```

The during backpropagation, I'm computing A = (B^T \times W)^T

```
A = B.transpose().mmul(W).transpose()
```

I've written the code so that everything is calculated in-place and is quite fast. But the Jblas transpose() method creates a completely new object and copies over all the data, which is quite expensive to call twice at every iteration. Is there any way to use a DoubleMatrix transpose during multiplication, without doing all this copying? Seems like it would be an easy thing to implement internally - using the same data object, but switching calls to rows and columns.

Answer (score 1):

A nice question that I asked myself as well.
I don't have an answer, but this simple fact can save one of the transpositions:

(B^T \times W) ^T = W^T * B

so you'd write

`A = W.transpose().mmul(B)`

Answer (score 0):

Author of nd4j here. We've added nd arrays and constant time transpose as well as matrix multiplies that work with various what we call "backends" one of which is jblas.

The API is very similar to jblas as well.

INDArray arr = Nd4j.create(2,2);
INDArray result = arr.mmul(arr);

The best part is you get cuda  and (soon to be added!) opencl for free.

We have migrated to netlib-java for most things but continue to offer jblas (as it's highly stable) but running the backends against each other in practice we have found the neat to do copy operations on jblas (since the internals don't support offsets)